# Test Summary Not Populated With Test Results in CircleCI

Tags: python, unit-testing, junit, continuous-integration, circleci

In CircleCI, I have a build executing automated tests. It generates tests results in an XML file using `nose2` and `junit` plugin. The complete path of the test result file is:

```
/project-folder/test/junit/test-result.xml
```

My CircleCI configuration in the file `/project-folder/.circleci/config.yml` contains this:

```
- store_artifacts:
    path: test/junit/test-results.xml
    destination: test-results

- store_test_results:
    path: test/junit/test-results.xml
```

When the build executes, it confirms that test results and artifacts are properly loaded:

```
Uploading artifacts
Uploading /home/circleci/repo/test/junit/test-results.xml to test-results
Uploaded /home/circleci/repo/test/junit/test-results.xml

Uploading test results
Archiving the following test results
  * /home/circleci/repo/test/junit/test-results.xml

Uploaded
```

However, the test results still do not appear in the **Test Summary** tab (see screenshot below).

[image: Test Summary Empty]

I have looked into the documentation here:

- [Store test results](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#store_test_results)
- [Metadata collection in custom steps](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/test-metadata/#metadata-collection-in-custom-test-steps)

But I fail to see what I am missing? I also do not understand what the variable `$CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS` refers to in the link above. What does it contain and how I should use it in my configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To upload tests results on circle, you have to speficy the main test folder not the files.

In your case it should be

```
- store_test_results:
    path: test
```

Comment: As simple as that... Thank you Laurent, it worked :)