# CircleCI: How do I configure test result storage?

Tags: junit, circleci, cypress

I'm using Cypress integration tests in a CircleCI environment. Currently my CircleCI configuration fails to store the test reports as artifacts and include a summary. The screenshots and videos are successfully stored. I'm including the `config.yml` and screenshots of the CircleCI dashboard.

I've consulted these pages of the CircleCI documentation:

- [Configuring CircleCI | `store_test_results`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#store_test_results)
- [Storing and Accessing Build Artifacts](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/)

And have noted the similarity of my question to ["Test Summary Not Populated With Test Results in CircleCI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236086/test-summary-not-populated-with-test-results-in-circleci).

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!

**`config.yml`**

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/nodefront
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:6
        environment:
          TERM: xterm
    parallelism: 1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restoring cached yarn dependencies
          key: v3-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: Installing dependencies with yarn
          command: |
            yarn install --frozen-lockfile
            yarn list
      - save_cache: 
          name: Caching yarn dependencies
          key: v3-deps-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache
      - run: mkdir -p integration-tests/test-results/junit integration-tests/cypress/videos integration-tests/cypress/screenshots
      - run:
          name: Running E2E tests with JUnit reporter
          command: $(yarn bin)/cypress run --project ./integration-tests --reporter junit --record --key 77ffe06e-0fe2-4b33-a5ff-4dcdf9e31c91
          environment: 
            MOCHA_FILE: integration-tests/test-results/junit/test-results-[hash].xml
          when: always
      - store_test_results:
          path: integration-tests/test-results
      - store_artifacts:
          path: integration-tests/test-results
      - store_artifacts:
          path: integration-tests/cypress/videos
      - store_artifacts:
          path: integration-tests/cypress/screenshots
```

**Screenshots**
[image: Test summary fails]
[image: Screenshots and videos succeed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I posted there have been some significant structural changes to the repository... but I'll post the relevant section of *config.yml* here. I can't pinpoint what we did to fix it, but part of it was giving the Cypress subfolder (*integration-tests*) its own *package.json*, putting the relevant scripts in there, and proceeding with a cleaner *.circleci/config.yml*. We took out the `mkdir` statement and the environment object.

```
test_cypress:
working_directory: ~/theintercept
docker:
  - image: cypress/base:6
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
parallelism: 1
steps:
  - checkout
  - restore_cache:
      name: Restoring cached yarn dependencies
      keys:
        - integration-tests-yarn-dependencies-{{ checksum "integration-tests/yarn.lock" }}
  - run:
      name: Installing dependencies with yarn
      command: |
        cd integration-tests
        yarn install --frozen-lockfile
        yarn list
  - save_cache:
      name: Caching yarn dependencies
      key: integration-tests-yarn-dependencies-{{ checksum "integration-tests/yarn.lock" }}
      paths:
        - ~/.cache/Cypress
        - ~/.cache/yarn
        - ~/theintercept/integration-tests/node_modules
  - run:
      name: Running E2E tests with JUnit reporter
      command: |
        cd integration-tests
        yarn test:record
  - store_test_results:
      path: integration-tests/test-results
  - store_artifacts:
      path: integration-tests/test-results
  - store_artifacts:
      path: integration-tests/test-artifacts
```

Comment: Anyone who has a fast way to indent all those lines without adding two more spaces in front of each one, please be my guest. :/